# filling combobox with observable list which consumed from wcf service

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, combobox

i am Beginner in WPF.i am trying to fill combobox with observable collection which is retrieved from wcf service

Combobox xaml code:

```
<ComboBox Name="CmbClass" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

consuming Service:

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client ClassList = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();

CmbClass.DataContext = ClassList.GetClassList();
```

i am not getting how to populate combobox. can anyone please help me?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

if you use codebehind anyway you can set the itemssource directly

```
<ComboBox Name="CmbClass" />

 ServiceReference1.Service1Client ClassList = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();

 CmbClass.ItemsSource = ClassList.GetClassList();
```

nevertheless you should look at MVVM and binding

Comment: Yes, if you want to use `Binding` then you should go for MVVM. Else the suggested answer will work.

Answer (score 0):

First set the `DataContext` of your `Window` to a class which contains the observable collection. you can do that right after `InitializeComponents()` in the constructor of the `Window.xaml.cs`

Then use this:

```
<ComboBox Name="CmbClass" ItemsSource="{Binding observableCollectionName}"
    DisplayMemberPath="nameToDisplay"/>
```

where observableCollectionName is the name of that observable collection. and nameToDisplay is the name of one of the properties in that collection which you want to see in the comboBox.

Answer (score 0):

```
CmbClass.ItemsSource = YourResult;
CmbClass.DisplayMemberPath = "Property you want to display";
CmbClass.SelectedValuePath = "Property you want to bind";
```

Comment: can you please tell me what is cbotest and what have to give in property..can you please give me example code

Comment: CmbClass is the name of your combobox and property is the attribute/field of your class

Answer (score 0):

I got how to fill combobox with observable collection whish is consumed from WCF
 Xaml Code:
 
 Consumingservice:

```
 public void GetClassList()
{
ServiceReference1.Service1Client ServiceClient = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
ObservableCollection<ClassDO> Classlist = ServiceClient.GetClassList();
Cmbclass.ItemsSource = Classlist;
Cmbclass.DisplayMemberPath = "classname";
//Cmbclass.se = "ClassID";
Cmbclass.SelectedValuePath = "classid";

}
```

Now call Getclasslist in windowload method